# Delete old backups alike Apple Time Machine does

Tags: bash, backup, rsync

Time Machine saves hourly backups for the past 24 hours, daily backups for the past month, and weekly backups for everything older than a month until the volume runs out of space. At that point, Time Machine deletes the oldest weekly backup ([Time Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_%28OS_X%29)).

I'm at the point where I already have the bash script (rsync) which makes backups every hour. The backups are folders named as "2015-01-01 08", where "08" is the hour.

At some point folders older than 24h need to be deleted. So I'm looking for this magic. I guess it will be kind of rm -R some_pattern. How would such a pattern look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 1-line command if running Linux (YMMV on OS X):

```
find /path/to/your/backups/ -type d -mtime +1 -exec rm -r "{}" \;
```

Note that this assumes your directories are not modified after creation.

You can omit the `-exec rm -r "{}" \;` part if you only want to output directory names to test the command.

Comment: To avoid that assumption, I would like to check the date from the name of the folder.

Comment: How to iterate over all the folders?